# Explicit float conversion in python gives ParseError

Tags: python

I'm learning python in Coursera, I tried the assignment for the course but am not getting the desired result. This program is supposed to extract '0.8475' and convert it to float before printing it.

```
text = "X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475";
pos=text.find('0');
s=text[pos:len(text)];
p=0.0;
p=(float)s;
print p;
```

Everytime I run this code, I get a `ParseError: bad input on line 5`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `p=(float)s;` must be `float(s)`., `(float)s` generally works in C++ and java, But in python the correct syntax is `float(s)` or more generally `type(s)`

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can you add this an answer and I'll mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ZdaR mentions, the call to the `float` function must pass the parameter inside the parentheses as `p = float(s)`.  I tested this in Python IDLE and the program worked correctly.

Also note that you should not end lines with `;` in Python.  The whitespace itself will handle that for you when you start a new line.